# An issue with cloth physics

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

So I rigged a character and added some clothing with some cloth physics applied. Everything was working perfectly fine but then after scaling the character down the cloth began to act strangely and no matter what I try I just can't seem to fix it.

[image: Before bake]

[image: After bake and running simulation]

Here's a link to download my project file to aid in answering my question.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/25vg9f9ds8oj4a8/WIP2.blend

Comment: Have you applied transforms? What exactly have you tried? Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/108362/edit) and add more information and in the future please use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload files to the site.

Comment: @Timaroberts The file size is too large for Blend-Exchange. The 
armature modifier and Cloth modifier has not been applied.

Comment: Can you pare the file down to just the relevant parts? 38 MB is a lot to download to help someone out, for people who have data limits or slow connections.